# Store vars in a separate JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

**Background:**
We've integrated cypress-testrail into our Cypress solution to report back to our 'source of truth'. This works up to the point where we have multiple TestRail projects so the project ID var needs to be updated before Cypress is launched (locally). Since we're not in a CI/CD state yet, we need to manage this for the local testers to have fewer hurdles (i.e. reduce the need to touch files).

**Current Issue:**
I want to use a 'testrail.json' file to store all the config settings that I will reference for the various runs.

Dumbing this down to a single file / config, I've moved the (functioning) 'testrail' section of the cypress.env.json into a testrail.json file and tried using a $ref to that file:

[cypress.env.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmRDL.png)

```
{
  "testrail": {
    "$ref": "./cypress/support/testrail.json",
  },
```

[referenced testrail.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvnq5.png)

```
{
  "testrail": {
    "domain": "redacted",
    "username": "redacted",
    "password": "redacted",
    "projectId": "redacted",
    "runName": "redacted",
    "closeRun": false,
    "screenshots": true
  },
```

but I'm returned a 'not configured' message so I assume I'm either doing something that can't (currently be done) or I'm doing it incorrectly...

**Question:**
What am I missing to get this working correctly while storing these variables in a referenced file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's any special significance to the `$ref` key in a JSON file. I looked through the [boxblinkracer/cypress-testrail](https://github.com/boxblinkracer/cypress-testrail) repo and can't see it using `$ref` to "include" the referenced file.

One thing that should work is adding a bit of code to your `cypress.config.js` file.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const TestRailReporter = require('cypress-testrail')

const testrailConfig = require('./cypress/support/testrail.json') // explicilty load here

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env = {
        ...config.env,
        ...testrailConfig    // merging that external file here
      }
      new TestRailReporter(on, config).register()  // using adjusted config
      return config
    }
  },
})
```